# Где взять эмулятор для андроид 2.3.3?

Tags: android

Где взять эмулятор для андроид 2.3.3?

Comment: А че сразу минусовать то? Нормальный вопрос начинающего чайника...

Comment: а кто минусует то?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо загрузить соответствующий SDK. Тогда при создании avd можно будет выбирать подходящий образ для эмулятора.

[image: снимок]

Answer (score 0):

Ставите сдк, там создаёте нужный эмулятор с андроидом.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

**Android SDK Manager**